# Как можно упростить код JS

Tags: javascript, for

Задача: распределить по 3 элемента (`.block-service`) в каждый контейнер `.about-page-process-row`. Всего контейнеров 5, а блоков будет 15.
[image: Так будут располагаться блоки .block-service внутри .about-page-process-row]

Этот код работает правильно, но есть ли возможность как-либо упростить цикл `for() {}`???

```
let blockService = document.querySelectorAll('.block-service'); // div-ы .block-service
let blocksArray = []; // сюда будут попадать все blockService для дальнейшей сортировки
let aboutPageProcessRow = document.querySelectorAll('.about-page-process-row'); // контейнеры


// Наполняю массив blocksArray и удаляю со страницы blockService
blockService.forEach(item => {
    blocksArray.push(item);
    item.remove();
});

// Для нечётных контейнеров flex-direction:row-reverse;, для чётных row
aboutPageProcessRow.forEach((container, i) => {
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        container.style.flexDirection = "row-reverse";
    } else {
        container.style.flexDirection = "row";
    }
})

// Наполняю контейнеры blockService-ами по 3шт. каждый контейнер в разных диапазонах
for (let i = 0; i < blocksArray.length; i++) {
    if (blocksArray.indexOf(blocksArray[i]) < 3) {
        aboutPageProcessRow[0].insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', blocksArray[i]);
    } else if (blocksArray.indexOf(blocksArray[i]) >= 3 && blocksArray.indexOf(blocksArray[i]) < 6) {
        aboutPageProcessRow[1].insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', blocksArray[i]);
    } else if (blocksArray.indexOf(blocksArray[i]) >= 6 && blocksArray.indexOf(blocksArray[i]) < 9) {
        aboutPageProcessRow[2].insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', blocksArray[i]);
    } else if (blocksArray.indexOf(blocksArray[i]) >= 9 && blocksArray.indexOf(blocksArray[i]) < 12) {
        aboutPageProcessRow[3].insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', blocksArray[i]);
    } else if (blocksArray.indexOf(blocksArray[i]) >= 12 && blocksArray.indexOf(blocksArray[i]) < 15) {
        aboutPageProcessRow[4].insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', blocksArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: добавь описание, что вообще происходит в данном коде.

Comment: момент, сейчас добавлю.

Comment: switch-case сразу приходит на ум, если в логику не вдаваться...

Comment: А, ну логика есть: aboutPageProcessRow[i] + ввести ещё один инкримент, j +3 например и blocksArray.indexOf(blocksArray[i]) >= j. P. S. хотя там 11 и 13 не вписывается, но можно массив из нужных цифер сделать и его перебирать в цикле по i.

Comment: Оставил комменты

Comment: Как я понимаю все item разные, поэтому делать `blocksArray.indexOf(blocksArray[i])` не имеет смысла т.к. он всегда будет равен `i`. Установку можно вынести в отдельную функция и вызывать setAboutPage(item, 0); Это сократит код в несколько раз + переписать на forEach куда тоже передается index: `blocksArray.forEach((item, index) => { ... }`.

Comment: @ГригорийКаданер, почему начиная с третьей строки (aboutPageProcessRow[3]) всего два элемента проверяется (9, 10) потом (11,12), потом (13,14)? Это опечатка?

Comment: @AlexKrass, `blocksArray.indexOf(blocksArray[i])` может отличаться от `i` если в массиве могут быть одинаковые элементы

Comment: @Grundy♦, точно. Я и не заметил опечатки, сейчас же поправлю!

Comment: @ГригорийКаданер, если это опечатка, то тогда у тебя последний контейнер пустым окажется

Comment: @Grundy, мне кажется `document.querySelectorAll` не должен вернуть дубликаты в любом случае, хотя из-за того, что я не уверен, то отдельно вставил фразу "как я понимаю все item разные".

Comment: @AlexKrass, да, в данном случае все ок, все элементы на странице - уникальны

Comment: @ГригорийКаданер, 15 блоков не делится на 6 контейнеров по три элемента. Тут что-то не так с задачей

Comment: @Grundy♦ понимаю. Но отсчёт вроде с 0 начинается. 1) if i < 3  (от 0 до 2) 2) if i >= 3 && i < 6 (от 3 до 5) 3) if i >= 6 && i < 9 (от 6 до 8) 4) if i >= 9 && i < 12 (от 9 до 11) 5) if i >= 12 && i < 15 (от 12 до 14) ну и 15 последний

Comment: Тогда код можно еще больше упростить, добавив в метод перебора aboutPageProcessRow.forEach сразу по три объекта через тот же splice, к примеру так: `blocksArray.splice(0,3).forEach(item => container.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', item))`. И тогда весь огромный кусок можно выкинуть.

Comment: @ГригорийКаданер, если у тебя 15 блоков, то индекс последнего будет 14. Если у тебя остается еще один с индексом 15, значит у тебя не 15 блоков, а 16

Comment: @Grundy точно ведь, какой невнимательный я оказался....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С каждой третьей итерацией нужно увеличивать индекс массива на один. Значит индекс массива равен номеру итерации деленому на три и округленному вниз.

```
// ... 

aboutPageProcessRow.forEach((container, i) => {
    container.style.flexDirection = (i % 2) ? 'row-reverse' : 'row';
});

for (let i = 0; i < blocksArray.length; i++) {
    const z = Math.min(Math.floor(i / 3), 5);
    aboutPageProcessRow[z].insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', blocksArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас шесть контейнеров, то элементов для заполнения должно быть 6 * 3 = 18. Код можно упростить до прямой вставки в цикле выше при переборе контейнеров. Единственное, что splice изменяет текущий массив, не забывайте об этом.

```js
let blockService = document.querySelectorAll('.block-service'); 
let blocksArray = []; 
let aboutPageProcessRow = document.querySelectorAll('.about-page-process-row'); 


blockService.forEach(item => {
    blocksArray.push(item);
    item.remove();
});


aboutPageProcessRow.forEach((container, i) => {
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        container.style.flexDirection = "row-reverse";
    } else {
        container.style.flexDirection = "row";
    }
    blocksArray
      .splice(0,3)
      .forEach(item => container.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', item));
})
```

```css
.about-page-process-row{
  outline: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.block-service{
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-page-process-row"></div>
<div class="about-page-process-row"></div>
<div class="about-page-process-row"></div>
<div class="about-page-process-row"></div>
<div class="about-page-process-row"></div>
<div class="about-page-process-row"></div>

<div class="block-service">1</div>
<div class="block-service">2</div>
<div class="block-service">3</div>
<div class="block-service">4</div>
<div class="block-service">5</div>
<div class="block-service">6</div>
<div class="block-service">7</div>
<div class="block-service">8</div>
<div class="block-service">9</div>
<div class="block-service">10</div>
<div class="block-service">11</div>
<div class="block-service">12</div>
<div class="block-service">13</div>
<div class="block-service">14</div>
<div class="block-service">15</div>
<div class="block-service">16</div>
<div class="block-service">17</div>
<div class="block-service">18</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Может так чуть короче и читаемо будет

```
let blockService = document.querySelectorAll('.block-service'); // div-ы .block-service
let blocksArray = []; // сюда будут попадать все blockService для дальнейшей сортировки
let aboutPageProcessRow = document.querySelectorAll('.about-page-process-row'); // контейнеры


// Наполняю массив blocksArray и удаляю со страницы blockService
blockService.forEach(item => {
    blocksArray.push(item);
    item.remove();
});

// Для нечётных контейнеров flex-direction:row-reverse;, для чётных row
aboutPageProcessRow.forEach((container, i) => {
     container.style.flexDirection = (i % 2 != 0) ? "row-reverse":"row";
    }
})

// Наполняю контейнеры blockService-ами по 3шт. каждый контейнер в разных диапазонах
function insertEl(v,i) {
  aboutPageProcessRow[i].insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', v)
}

blocksArray.forEach((v,i) =>{
  if (i < 3) return insertEl(v,0);
  if (i >= 3 && i < 6) return insertEl(v,1);
  if (i >= 6 && i < 9) return insertEl(v,2);
  if (i >= 9 && i < 11) return insertEl(v,3);
  if (i >= 11 && i < 13) return insertEl(v,4);
  if (i >= 13 && i < 15) return insertEl(v,5);
})
```